# Is there any way to see teradata username(schemaname) completely if the schema name has more than 30 characters?

Tags: database, teradata

I want to fetch all teradata schema names and show it to the user. I have few schemas and it has more than 35 characters in the name. I tried to fecth schemas from DBC.Databases   but schema names are truncated to 30 characters in the metadata table. Is there any metadata table from which i can get complete schema name without truncation

Answer (score 1):

Try `DBC.DatabasesV`. It generally will not have the 30 characters limit.

If you look into the definition, `DBC.Databases` (without trailing 'V') is a view on top of DBC.DBase. The `DatabaseName` field in that view is defined as:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(TRANSLATE(DBase.DatabaseName USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR) FROM 1 FOR 30)
        AS CHAR(30)) (NAMED DatabaseName),
```

`DBC.DatabasesV` (with trailing 'V') also points to the same underlying table but does not have the same `CAST` on it

```
DBase.DatabaseName (NAMED DatabaseName),
```

Comment: Cool,  I am able to fetch full schema name. Thanks

Comment: @ramya: Teradata's Data Dictionary switched from `CHAR(30) LATIN` to `VARCHAR(128) UNICODE` in TD12 and since then the old dbc-views (without `V`) have been deprecated...